# bootstrap-vue component renders as comment

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, bootstrap-vue

In my vue project some bootstrap-vue components renders fine but others render as a HTML comment. In this example they both components show up fine in the Vue Dev tool panel. I have added a "normal" input field just to see if that gets rendered ok.

```
<template>
    <div class="list-group">
        <div>Test</div>
        <b-form-input v-model="text1"
                      type="text"
                      placeholder="Enter your name"></b-form-input>
        <b-form-textarea id="textarea1"
                         v-model="text"
                         placeholder="Enter something"
                         :rows="3"
                         :max-rows="6"></b-form-textarea>
        <input type="text"/>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
    import {Component, Vue} from 'vue-property-decorator';

    @Component
    export default class ProjectList extends Vue {
        text = 'text';
        text1 = 'text1';
    }
</script>
```

But get rendered as:

[image]

[image]

I would expect to see both the input fields in the browser but I only see the textarea and the "normal" input field. I see no errors in the log. What could I be missing?

Comment: That's completely normal. It's probably because there is an element there where it is conditionally rendered.

Comment: @Terry thanks for your comment. Do you mean in the b-input component? I do not see that in the doc: https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/form-input. Note there is no v-if in my code.

Comment: That’s how VueJS works, nothing to do with bootstrap VueJS plug-in.

Comment: @Terry ahh...sorry. Maybe my question was not clear on this, but I do not see the input field in the browser only the textarea is visible. Why do I see one and not the other? I expect to see both :-)

Comment: I noticed that you are nesting those elements directly in `<ul>`. The only valid direct descendent of `<ul>` is `<li>`. Try updating your markup and see if anything changes.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the question. It did not help with a div though.

Comment: is your v-model pointing to a real property?

Comment: @FailedUnitTest yes it is. I have added the full code sample to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found a solution:

Instead of importing:

```
import Vue from 'vue'    
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'

Vue.use(BootstrapVue);
```

I import:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.esm';

Vue.use(BootstrapVue);
```

And now everything works fine. I am not sure why as the former is described in the bootstrap-vue documentation. Maybe its because I am using TypeScript..?

Comment: Hello Jens, I was trying to spin up a vue project with TypeScript where I'm facing difficulty to incorporate bootstrapVue. Right now:
`import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'`
Doesn't work. So I tried to import from `bootstrap-vue.esm` but the following error is showing: Couldn't find declaration file for module 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.esm'.....

Do you have any idea or could you please provide a working sample of a bootstrap-vue+ts project? Thanks.

Comment: @Ruhshan I am using the approach described in the BootstrapVue guide now as my initial problem is gone. Try to delete your node_modules folder and run npm install. I think that did the trick.